# Cakephp 3 : How to add order in queryBuilder for associative data?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

Here I have a events field which have a realtion with passwords.I need to order all passwords by download_count DESC. So I have tried below code. It's not giving me any error but desc is not working.

```
 $event = $this->Events->get($id, [
                  'contain' => [
                      'EventPasswordAll.Passwords' => [
                          'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
                              return $q->order(['download_count' => 'DESC']);
                          }
                      ]
                  ]
             ]);
```

I have also tried

```
 return $q->order(['Passwords.download_count' => 'DESC']);
```

I get the query

```
SELECT EventPasswordAll.id AS `EventPasswordAll__id`, EventPasswordAll.event_id AS `EventPasswordAll__event_id`, EventPasswordAll.password_id AS `EventPasswordAll__password_id`, Passwords.id AS `Passwords__id`, Passwords.name AS `Passwords__name`, Passwords.collection_id AS `Passwords__collection_id`, Passwords.photo_count AS `Passwords__photo_count`, Passwords.download_count AS `Passwords__download_count`, Passwords.created AS `Passwords__created`, Passwords.expires_at AS `Passwords__expires_at`, Passwords.recommended AS `Passwords__recommended`, Passwords.accepted AS `Passwords__accepted`, Passwords.user_id AS `Passwords__user_id` FROM event_password_all EventPasswordAll INNER JOIN passwords Passwords ON Passwords.id = (EventPasswordAll.password_id) WHERE EventPasswordAll.event_id in (14)
```

How to add order in queryBuilder for associative data ?

Comment: What does the generated query look like?

Comment: I have edited my question @ndm.

Comment: Looks like `Passwords` is associated with `EventPasswordAll` as `EventPasswordAll belongsTo Passwords`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an association of `EventPasswordAll belongsTo Passwords`, the `passwords` table record will be retrieved via a join, as can be seen in the query. In this case there is no query for `Passwords`, and thus the query builder is not being invoked.

You have to set the order for the `EventPasswordAll` query builder instead, like

```
$event = $this->Events->get($id, [
    'contain' => [
        'EventPasswordAll' => [
            'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
                return $q->order(['Passwords.download_count' => 'DESC']);
            },
            'Passwords'
        ]
    ]
]);
```